# Include related topic link (learn more button) instead of go get it button in the badge tooltips, if necessary

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, tooltips

In the `privilege` tooltips we see `learn more` button and button link give us details information on related topic/rules.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) & picture below

[image]

In the `badge` tooltips we see some `badge` tooltips has `go get it` button  **picture below**

**Example as**

In the questions `badge` tooltips has `go get it` button...

[image]

but In the `marshal badge` tooltips does not have `go get it` button..

[image]

Also in the `badge` tooltip `go get it` button does not carry important/useful link

Some `badge` require to provide details information … they have conditional logic and formula

**Example Curious `badge`:**  A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5. (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5 *(The formula collated from stack overflow network)*

Also I see in `retired badge` name `documentation beta` - there is note ***Contributed 3+ substantive pieces of documentation during the private beta***. there are no related link or learn more options ..

In this small piece of note raise in mind  many questions about topic and rules …

[image]

**Feature Request**

**So if `badge` has complicated rule/formula, it will be more useful if Stack Exchange put related topic links**

**Personal Opinion** It will be better user experience for newly user also it will reduce confusion and asking questions on unnecessary topic...

Comment: Marshall isn't complicated but it does have a fairly simple but unique set of criteria. As for the badge on documentation... It is a long story...

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I know... actually I try to show difference between question and marshal badge tooltips . Also I write _if necessary include button_ in my question title ...